# some basic queries regarding value stack in struts 2?

Tags: struts2, struts, valuestack

I am new to strut 2 though I have worked on struts 1.2.In one of the pexisting project jsp file I have following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var relationshipData = { // line1
    page : '<s:property value="displayPage" />', // line2
    records : '<s:property value="customerRelations.size" />', // line3
    rows : [ <s:iterator value="customerRelations" status="iterStatus"> // line4
      { id : '<s:property value="relationId" />', 
        cell : [ '<s:property value="relationDesc" escapeJavaScript="true" />' ] } <s:if test="!#iterStatus.last">,</s:if> //line5
        </s:iterator>] // line6
  };
</script>
```

Request is coming `CustomerRelationAction.java` which has method `getCustomerRelations()` and `getRelationId()`.

here are the questions :-

1. I put breakpoint inside method `getCustomerRelations()`.i see flow is coming four time inside this method. Two times at line 3 and another two times at line 4.
   As per my understanding flow should come only 1 time i.e at line 3. Once it completes getCustomerRelations at line 3 , should not put its value in value stack so that
   it can refer to it nextime it is refered (like it is being reffered at line 14 again)?
2. `getCustomerRelations()` method returns the list of `CustomerRelationData` objects where `CustomerRelationData` class also contains the `getRelationId()` method.Now at line
   5 we are refering value="relationId at line 5. On Which  object(CustomerRelationAction.java or CustomerRelationData),  getRelationId() method will be called?
   even i am not sure will the list object CustomerRelationData will be present on value stack or not?If yes at which line it will be put in value stack?
3. Now the iterator completes at line 6.After that,now i refer the code `<s:property value="relationId" />` again, On Which  object(CustomerRelationAction.java or CustomerRelationData), 
   getRelationId() method will be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** I don't know why you think calling for a property of `customerRelations` and then using `customerRelations` in an iterator tag would only call `getCustomerRelations()` once; you're using it twice, so at a minimum it'll get called twice.

If you want to keep a reference to it, use `<s:set>` to create a new reference to the collection. I don't see a point to doing so, however, unless your getter is doing something time-consuming.

I don't see the same behavior. Given the question's `<script>` snippet, it renders thusly (assuming a dummy, three-element list with sample data):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var relationshipData = { // line1
    records : '3', // line3
    rows : [  // line4
      { id : '1',
        cell : [ 'desc 1' ] } , //line5
       // line4
      { id : '2',
        cell : [ 'desc 2' ] } , //line5
       // line4
      { id : '3',
        cell : [ 'desc 3' ] }  //line5
      ] // line6
  };
</script>
```

And the log output, with a debug statement in the getter, is this:

```
2012-01-19 13:58:10,552 DEBUG [TextExampleAction.java:18] : Enter.
2012-01-19 13:58:10,571 DEBUG [TextExampleAction.java:18] : Enter.
```

I'm more likely to believe the JSP/JS/etc. at this point.

**2)** The iterator tag puts each object on the top of the stack, as described in the [tag docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator.html). The top of the stack is the first object that will be used to get the value of `relationId`. If it isn't found on the stack top, OGNL will traverse the value stack until either the property is found, or there's no more stack.

**3)** See the previous answer: once you're out of the iterator, there's no longer a customer relation on the stack, and you're back to the action.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your answer and patience.As you said , The iterator tag puts each object on the top of the stack. Does s:property tag also put the retrieved object in value stack (like will '<s:property value="displayPage" />' tag put the value of displayPage in value stack )? As per my observation in debugger mode it did not.

Comment: @MSach: property tag will fetch the value from valuestack.in case of iterator it will push the object on top of value stack so that same can be retrieved in your page